# How to include Source Branch name or pull request ID in ADO release title?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a CD release pipeline which gets deployed whenever new Pull Request (PR) build is succeeded. I want to include the source branch name of that PR as well as PR id in my release title.

I tried below variables in title, but they didn't work:

$(system.pullRequest.sourceBranch)

$(BUILD.PullRequest.SourceBranch)

$(BUILD.PullRequest.ID)

I just don't want to use $(Build.SourceBranch) or $(Build.SourceBranchName) as it doesn't give me expected value.

My expected release title:
"PR Run- personal/ak/randombuild with PRID 1234 - 01"

Comment: Do you create PR manually?

Comment: Yes, manually. After completing that PR, a PR build automatically gets triggered. Once that build is successful, a release gets deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PR variables are not available in the release scope: [How do I manage the names for new releases?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-manage-the-names-for-new-releases)

However,. you can use BuildId to get the detailed build information via Rest API and update your release name.

The PowerShell example:

```
$user = ""
$token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$orgUrl = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI"
$teamProject = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"
$currentBuildId = "$env:BUILD_BUILDID"

$restApiGetBuild = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds/$currentBuildId`?api-version=6.0"

function InvokeGetRequest ($GetUrl)
{   
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}

$resBuild = InvokeGetRequest $restApiGetBuild

if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($resBuild.triggerInfo.'pr.number'))
{
    Write-Host "##vso[release.updatereleasename]PR Run - PR ID" $resBuild.triggerInfo.'pr.number'
}
```

Add that as a step in the release. The result:

[image]

Do not forget to provide access to the token for your release pipeline:

[image]

Comment: Actually, PR ID is available in a release via BUILD_PULLREQUEST_ID environment variable

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there.
The variable you need is $(Build.PullRequest.SourceBranch)
Since your release pipeline is triggered by a pull request it will be available.

But I have to warn you that this variable itsn't documented by Microsoft.

Take a look at this image
[Variable available at the release pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltorC.png)

Comment: Is it not documented because it doesn't work?  It appears, that if your release is triggered by a commit to the branch, you can't get the branch name in a simple variable.  Such an obvious feature to have, it sets other things like buildnumber, but not what is needed for what I want to do...

Comment: Build.SourceBranch Worked for me, in spite of saying it is a full path name with lots of extra stuff, it only contained the branch name, which is what I needed